# texture error after using screw modifier

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I used screw modifier and there are dark spots

I want to remove the dark parts and make it clean

please help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices, it will create overlapping faces when you'll use the *Screw* modifier, so select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. Also you can simplify your mesh this way to avoid useless inner faces:

[image]